# jQuery if statement, cannot figure out show all in form select

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I have a form select which changes the div based on what is selected. It was working the way I wanted but I want a new feature and the conditional statement is not working. When a user selects all events, it needs to show all the events but the logic is not working.

The code is set up in http://jsfiddle.net/RhW89/

HTML

```
<form>
<select id="eventFilter">
  <option value="all">All Events</option>
  <option value="a">AAA</option>
  <option value="b">BBB</option>
  <option value="c">CCC</option>
 </select>
</form>

<div id="displayInfo">    
    <div id="a" class="event">Content from AAA</div>
    <div id="b" class="event">Content from BBB</div>
    <div id="c" class="event">Content from CCC</div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#eventFilter').change(function(){
    if(
    $(this).val("all") ){
        alert("showeverything");
        $('.event').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.event').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    }
});
                      ​
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$(this).val("all")` which sets the value to all, to:

```
$(this).val() == "all"
```

Which will compare the current value to the string "all".

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RhW89/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You were setting the value with your code instead of making a comparison. Use this:

```
if($(this).val() == "all")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing "all" to `.val()` which in turn sets the value

Using `.val()` without passing a value returns the value so you end up with

```
$('#eventFilter').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "all" ){
        alert("showeverything");
        $('.event').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.event').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    $('#eventFilter').change(function(){

    if(this.value =="all" )
    {   
        $('.event').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.event').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    }
});
```